# call a java webservice using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, web-services

I created a java Restfull webservice using patterns in netbeans and run the project in one machine. How can i call this web service from another machine in javascript

The webservice class is

```
package com.gdb.webapi;


import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import static javax.ws.rs.HttpMethod.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author suhail
 */
@Path("displaylist")
public class DisplaylistResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of DisplaylistResource
     */
    public DisplaylistResource() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of
     * com.gdb.appconstant.DisplaylistResource
     *
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getJson() {
        //TODO return proper representation object
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of DisplaylistResource
     *
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String putJson(String content) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(content);
        return "true";
    }



}
```

I want to call the post method using ajax

Comment: I'd put a `@Path` annotation on the methods as well as `@WebParam` on the parameter for a start. Then call the webservice from javascript as you would do with any other url/form.

Answer (score 0):

Create path of your service call. http://YOUR IP/PROJECT NAME/ACTION NAME.

eg

```
 function fun() 
{
   var data="hello";
   $.get("http://localhost/projectNAME/HelloWorld", function(response) {
        data = response;
   }).error(function(){
  alert("Sorry could not proceed");
});

   return data;
}
```

and also put @path annotation for methods, which ll decide which method is going to call.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the *fetch* polyfill -> https://github.com/github/fetch. Look at the readme to see how to post data to a REST service:

```
fetch('/users', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'Hubot',
    login: 'hubot',
  })
})
```

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to do this from a browser, which might not be the case, but the principles are the same.

Comment: You will need to setup CORS correctly on the server that exposes the web services. This can be done with a servlet filter (tomcat already has one).

Comment: CORS = Cross Origin Resource Sharing